# Black screen after install ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I have just installed ubuntu 18.04 on Asus expert book and after running, I get this black screen:
[image]

Comment: Do you have have nVidia? https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it  But if very new system, 20.04 or soon to be released 22.04 may be better. And those allow safe boot to include video driver and then option to install proprietary drivers during install, so it should then work on reboot without nomodetset boot parameter.

Comment: Yes I have nvidea. Dou you think that I should install 20.04 instead of 18.04 ?

Comment: Yes, but boot with Safe Boot and then also choose to install proprietary drivers.

Comment: Yes, I have install 20.04 and it's ok. Thanks